# how to configuration multiple dispatch servlet use java annotation in spring3

Tags: spring-mvc

As spring could let you have multiple dispatch servlet using their own xml configuration [servlet-name]-servlet.xml.
I am wondering how to do the same thing using java annotation configuration class rather than xml file?
for instance:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>em</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

with web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ap</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ap/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>em</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/em/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please see below configuration for working with Annotation.
Also, below is just a working code of my project, so please modify as per your need.

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.on.transport" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Keep all your class inside this package as it will scan inside this package. (com.on.transport), change as per your need to all places needed.

```
@Controller
public class AdminEmployeeManipulation {

    @RequestMapping(value="/selectEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView employeeManipulation(Principal principal) {
    }

    // Add as many function you need based on @RequestMapping.
}
```

For detailed explanation refer : http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: thanks mkyong!!!  you showed us how to configure a single servlet and completely missed the point of the question... and the answer for that matter.